# MongoDB Won't Connect

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, dotenv

I've been trying to get my react app to connect to my database. I was getting a connection when I hardcoded the server in to the db.js file (see below), but once I started trying to use a env file for the server I am now getting an error message that can't seem to fix. The error message I have been getting when I run `node server.js`

```
/Users/home/Developer Files/inkbucket/server/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/lib/index.js:9
    return (connectionString.startsWith('mongodb://') ||
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')
    at connectionStringHasValidScheme (/Users/home/Developer Files/inkbucket/server/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/lib/index.js:9:30)
    at new ConnectionString (/Users/home/Developer Files/inkbucket/server/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/lib/index.js:85:34)
    at parseOptions (/Users/home/Developer Files/inkbucket/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/connection_string.js:197:17)
    at new MongoClient (/Users/home/Developer Files/inkbucket/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:46:63)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/home/Developer Files/inkbucket/server/server.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)

Node.js v18.13.0
```

I'm not sure why I use my .env file do I start getting connection issues and could use some advice on the matter. I have attached the files below, and thank you for any indication on what is causing my mistake here.

**db.js** without .env connecting to db and working

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const uri =
  "mongodb+srv://wynter:fakepassword@inkbucket.dvufxul.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Unable to connect to MongoDB");
  } else {
    console.log("Connected to DB");
  }
});
```

**db.js** not working

```
require("dotenv").config();
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Unable to connect to MongoDB");
  } else {
    console.log("Connected to DB");
  }
});
```

**server.js**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const db = require("./db");

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

**.env**

```
MONGODB_URI="mongodb+srv://wynter:fakepassword@inkbucket.dvufxul.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

Comment: Have you tried simply logging the `uri` value to check that it is the expected value? FYI, you should only ever use `require("dotenv").config()` **once**

Comment: It sounds like `uri` is `undefined` which means your `.env` file is probably in the wrong location. It should be in the current working directly, ie the same directory as `server.js`

Comment: Yup, that did it. I have two folders one client, and one for server. I thought my .env is suppose to be in the root folder for the app. I moved it to /server and its good. Should I have multi .env files? one for each the client and one for the sever?

Comment: You can specify the location in the `config()` parameters. By default, dotenv looks in the working directory, ie the directory you're in when running `node`

Comment: It won't impact my app if I use two .env files will it? Honestly if that works, then I'd rather just do that for ease

Comment: You can have as many as you want but it's [not recommended within the same app](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#should-i-have-multiple-env-files)